# Using eth.subscribe() with Web3.js isnt returning any result

Tags: web3js, infura

```
const { Web3 } = require('web3');

// Replace with your Infura project ID
const API_KEY = ''"
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(`wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/${API_KEY}`));

const ERC20_TRANSFER_SIGNATURE = '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef';
const TokenAddress = ''

var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: TokenAddress, 
    topics: [ERC20_TRANSFER_SIGNATURE]
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Im trying to listen for events for a specific token address, but nothing is logged. I've done my googling and researching, and the code is directly from the Web3js documentation.

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-subscribe.html

Nothing is printed in console and im unsure what the cause is. Any suggestions is greatly appriciated.